# Set Groove Music sound Windows 10

Tags: audio, windows-10, modern-ui, groove-music

On Windows 7 I used the sound mixer to manage sound between applications but with Windows 10, Groove Music doesn't appear in the sound mixer. 
It's a problem because I don't hear correctly when somebody speak on Mumble for example.

Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Get EqualizerAPO & the "Peace interface" (both free) & both work seamlessly & brilliantly for groove player on Windows 10 64 & 32 . Just what you need to tailor the "Johnny One Note Sound" of the Groove player.